# Printing XMacro struct to the console with C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, cout, x-macros

I'm playing around with structs and classes and I saw a really cool bit of coding I wanted to try out: the x-macro.

My code is broken up into 3 bits, the header, the x-macro, and the main cpp file. The program isn't finished and there's code coverage and polishing to do still, but I'm trying to build a struct with an x-macro then I want to print the contents of the struct to the screen.

Here's my x-macro

```
#define X_AIRCRAFT  \
X(int, Crew) \
X(int, SeatingCapacity) \
X(int, Payload) \
X(int, Range) \
X(int, TopSpeed) \
X(int, CargoCapacity) \
X(int, FuelCapacity) \
X(int, Engines) \
X(int, Altitude) \
X(double, mach) \
X(double, Wingspan)
```

Here's my header (pretty barren right now)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef X_AIRCRAFT
#include "xmacro.xmacro"
#endif // !



using namespace std;


typedef struct {
#define X(type, name) type name;

    X_AIRCRAFT
#undef X
}Public_Airplane;

//Prototypes
void iterater(Public_Airplane *p_a);
```

Here's my `main()` (I've cut out a bunch of code here. What I did here, in summary, was build an Airplane class with different properties. I then built three different subclasses that inherited the properties of Airplane and did their own stuff. So I'll avoid posting the classes at all, unless you guys think that my problem lies there. What I'll do is just post the function that isn't working properly...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "aircraft.h"

#ifndef X_AIRCRAFT
#include "xmacro.xmacro"
#endif // !


using namespace std;




    int main()
{
    Public_Airplane p_a;

     iterater(&p_a);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



void iterater(Public_Airplane *p_a)
{

    //I want to print to screen the contents of my x-macro (and therefore my struct)
#define X(type, name) cout << "Value: = " << name;
    X_AIRCRAFT
#undef X
}
```

I've never worked with macros before, which is why I'm trying to do so now. But to my understanding, the preprocessed code should look something like this:

```
int crew;
int SeatingCapacity;
int Payload
int Range;              
int TopSpeed;           
int CargoCapacity;      
int FuelCapacity;       
int Engines;            
int Altitude;           
double mach;            
double Wingspan;

cout << "Value: = " << Crew; (and so on down the list).
```

What am I doing wrong that is keeping me from getting the code output above?

Comment: Rewrite `cout << "Value: = " name;` as `cout << "Value: = " << name;`, perhaps?

Comment: I just noticed the typo. I added the << into my code and no dice.

Answer (score 1):

You ultimately want to generate code that looks like this:

```
void iterater(Public_Airplane* p_a) {
    cout << "Crew = " << p_a->Crew << endl;
    cout << "SeatingCapacity = " << p_a->SeatingCapacity << endl;
    ...
}
```

The general pattern is to print out a string representation of the name, then an equals sign, then to use the arrow operator to select that member out of the class. Here's one way to do this:

```
void iterater(Public_Airplane *p_a)
{
    #define X(type, name) cout << #name << " = " << p_a->name << endl;
    X_AIRCRAFT
    #undef X
}
```

This uses the stringizing operator # to convert the name into a quoted version of itself.

Comment: I'm about to give that a try. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Your code makes more sense, but when I step through the program, it passes through the function without executing the code.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but when I preprocess to a file, I don't see the preprocessor's code. I thought I could expect to see int Crew; int SeatingCapacity; ... and so on. But the file has none of that. Is there some include that I need to use in order to use xmacros?

Comment: This code is working fine on my system - perhaps we have something set up differently? I'd recommend posting a new question with the current version of your code so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.